# CakePHP 3 - Vendors

Tags: php, cakephp

Como faço para importar um vendor no cakephp3?

tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS  . 'Dailymotion' . DS . 'Dailymotion.php');
```

mas ele me retorna o erro:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/var/www/Projeto/src/Vendor/Dailymotion/Dailymotion.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/Projeto/src/Controller/EpisodesController.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir da versão 3, o diretório Vendor foi movido para o ROOT da aplicação. Você pode definir uma constante no bootstrap.php para o diretório vendor, já que essa constante já não   é padrão na versão.

```
define('VENDOR', ROOT . DS . 'vendor' .DS);
```

E chamar:

```
 require_once(VENDOR . 'Dailymotion' . DS . 'Dailymotion.php');
```